# How to rebind ctrl+shift+q to @ using xbindkeys?

Tags: xubuntu, xbindkeys

I'm trying to remapp <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to show an `@`.

I'm using `xbindkeys -k` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. Output:

```
"NoCommand"
    m:0x81 + c:11
    Shift+Mod5 + 2
```

Thus I put the following in `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '@'"
    m:0x81 + c:11
    Shift+Mod5 + 2
```

Then reloading with `xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc`.

Result: pressing the key combination shows: `⅛`

Why?

ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

You must use only one of the lines

```
m:0x81 + c:11
Shift+Mod5 + 2
```

in `~/.xbindkeysrc`, so delete or comment out (w/ `#`) the other (usually it doesn't matter which, but the one starting w/ `m:` should be more universal)

Comment: Neither using exclusively the m: tag nor the key command line did work. I'm still getting `⅛` as result when pressing the mapped keys.

Comment: Try reloading the config w/ `xbindkeys -p`. I don't have `xvkbd`, so cannot really comment on this.  Does your command (on its own) display `@` somewhere? It may be a keyboard layout problem or `xvkbd` interfering w/ `xbindkeys` or... On my system (Ubuntu 16.04), `xbindkeys -k` and Ctrl+Alt+q gives `m:0xc + c:24` and `Control+Alt + q`. Try these codes, too

Comment: This still gives me `⅛`.

Comment: Try also `Shift+2` w/ and w/out `Scroll Lock` on (`Mod5` is `Scroll Lock`, which should be ignored by `xbindkeys` by default)